# Preventing JQuery from retrieving scripts everytime for a cached HTML request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an header file that is loaded and inserted at the top of all my pages. This header file is loaded with the following ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/header.html',
        cache: true,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function ( data ) {
            $( 'body').prepend( data );
        }
});
```

The HTML file is cached, so when the user visits one page, upon navigating to other pages the header will load much faster at the top of the other pages. The problem is that there is a `<script>` tag inside that HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/header.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

And this script is not cached. I checked the Network activity tab of Firebug and the script is requested with a unique number at the end of it:

```
GET http://localhost/header.js?_=1362254276028
```

How can I ask JQuery to load the script from cache just like the HTML page instead of getting it every time a page is loaded?

Comment: I am not that this helps, but have you tried to disable cache using [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup)? I mean [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript) for example does not allow to disable cache (only using ajaxSetup)

Comment: that actually helped but when I use ajaxSetup() to turn on the cache, all subsequent ajax calls will be cached and that's not good. So I tried turning on the cache right before getting the HTML and then turning it off immediately after that. Unfortunately getting the `header.js` script happens after that so it will not be loaded from cache anyway.

Comment: You can reset default ajax setting in the included script (header.js)